# Sequelize plain object returns empty - curly braces misbehaving

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Scenario:
When I was trying to get a plain object from a sequelize query, I got a set of 3 empty objects.

Solution:
After hours of trying to figure it out, I noticed that when I surrounded the message.get method with curly braces it stops working normaly.

Can someone please explain why this happens? By surrounding the message.get({plain:true}) method with curly braces it gives a set of empty objects (3 empty objects in this particular case).

The original code:

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const {Message} = require('../models/');


router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {

        const dbMessagesData = await Message.findAll();

        // HERE *****************************************
        const messages = dbMessagesData.map(message => {
                message.get({plain: true});
            }
        );


        // MESSAGES CONTENT
        messages.forEach(( element , index, array)=>{
             console.log("---> element :" + JSON.stringify (element) );
        });

        res.render('homepage', {messages});
    } catch
        (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e.message);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Terminal:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\giann\Dropbox\IdeaProjects\Homework\14-Tech-Blog\server.js
(node:97384) [SEQUELIZE0002] DeprecationWarning: The logging-option should be either a function or false. Default: console.log
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Server listening on port 3000
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title`, `content`, `created_at` AS `createdAt`, `updated_at` AS `updatedAt`, `user_id`, `user_id` AS `UserId` FROM `Message` AS `Message`;
---> element :undefined
---> element :undefined
---> element :undefined
```

Now, I took away the curly braces block:

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const {Message} = require('../models/');


router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {

        const dbMessagesData = await Message.findAll();

        //HERE - curly braces removed ****************
        const messages = dbMessagesData.map(message => 
                message.get({plain: true})
            
        );


        // MESSAGES CONTENT
        messages.forEach(( element , index, array)=>{
             console.log("---> element :" + JSON.stringify (element) );
        });

        res.render('homepage', {messages});
    } catch
        (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e.message);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Terminal:

```````
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\giann\Dropbox\IdeaProjects\Homework\14-Tech-Blog\server.js
(node:188548) [SEQUELIZE0002] DeprecationWarning: The logging-option should be either a function or false. Default: console.log
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Server listening on port 3000
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title`, `content`, `created_at` AS `createdAt`, `updated_at` AS `updatedAt`, `user_id`, `user_id` AS `UserId` FROM `Message` AS `Message`;
---> element :{"id":1,"title":"Title 1","content":"Hey, this is the first message","createdAt":"2021-08-23T17:29:56.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-08-23T17:29:56.000Z","user_id":1,"UserId":1}
---> element :{"id":2,"title":"Title 2","content":"Hey, this is the second message","createdAt":"2021-08-23T17:29:56.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-08-23T17:29:56.000Z","user_id":2,"UserId":2}
---> element :{"id":3,"title":"Title 3","content":"Hey, this is the third message","createdAt":"2021-08-23T17:29:56.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-08-23T17:29:56.000Z","user_id":3,"UserId":3}
``````

What am I missing here??
```````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its just syntax (learn it by heart)

```
(x) => x
```

is equivalent to

```
(x) => {
 return x;
}
```

if you dont put the return it this second form you will have no return, which means
it will return undefined. hence what you see.

in your exemple this should work

```
const messages = dbMessagesData.map(message => {
                return message.get({plain: true});
            }
        );
```

Comment: MY GOSH! I'm glad nobody's life depends on my code! 

Thank you Raphael.